# How to get "path" of pic in internal storage and display it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, path

I was searching a lot of posts about "how to get the path of picture exist in the internal or external storage" and display it.

I used tried a lot of codes but no one worked!

Answer (score 0):

If it must be a file, integrate some [file picker library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/35) in your app.

Android's built-in options, such as `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, are for *content*, not *files*. Through those, the user may choose lots of things that are not files that your app can access.

In terms of displaying it, use [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to apply the image to an `ImageView`.